# Getting authorization_code and result after successfully linked account

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, botframework

According to [Facebook Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/account-linking)

When account linking is successfully, i want to get authorization_code. And result from account linking process.

I tried :

```
msg.ChannelData.result
msg.ChannelData.account_linking.status
```

with no success.

What about you guys ? How do you handle account linking ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dynamic jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(activity.ChannelData.ToString());

// Process FB account linking callback
string status = jsonResponse.account_linking?.status?.ToString();

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(status))
    return false;

string linkedUserId = jsonResponse.account_linking?.authorization_code?.ToString();
```